# Set PATH for a Linux GUI Application

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, dash

Here's the setup:

- I'm running MX Linux
- I'm trying to work on a React Native application in Android Studio
- React Native relies on NodeJS (and thus the `node` executable) to be available
- Android Studio starts via a shell script (`studio.sh`)
- I use a tool called `asdf` for version management of things like NodeJS, which sets up shims to redirect the `node` executable to a versioned one
- Normally, the shims to redirect the `node` command are loaded inside `~/.bashrc` (or in my case, `~/.zshrc` because I use zsh shell)
- When I go to the terminal and output `$PATH`, my shims are loaded in there and show in the `PATH`
- When I run Android Studio via my `.desktop` file (whose Exec line looks like: `Exec=/home/myuser/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`) it **cannot locate the `node` executable**
- It seems like the Linux distro I'm using (MX Linux) uses `dash` as its default shell
- If I run `cat /proc/<PID>/environ` for the Android Studio PID I notice the `PATH` is missing the shims
- I've tried:

  - Altering the Exec line in the desktop file to run `bash /home/myuser/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`
  - Altering the Exec line to add additional PATH values like `env PATH="$HOME/.asdf/shims" /home/myuser/...`
  - Altering `~/.profile` to set up the PATH with the shim values

I've tried everything I can think of to pass these PATH values along to the Android Studio shell script and nothing seems to be working. The only approach that works is for me to start Android Studio from the terminal, and then the PATH is (I assume) inherited and it can find the `node` executable.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a wrapper script which I execute from the .desktop file entry.

My .desktop file just points to Exec a new wrapper Bash script I made called `studio.bash`, whose contents look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
. $HOME/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

This seems to correctly run the asdf shell script in order to set up the shims, and then call the shell script to start Android Studio. Took me forever, but it works. Would love other (better?) suggestions to solve this without all the rigamarole.

I think a big part of the problem is confusion around the fact that asdf specifies itself as a `bash` script, but `studio.sh` specifies itself as a `sh` script, and `sh` maps to `dash` on my system. With those three things combined, trying to determine which of `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc. were relevant was a bit mind-bending to me.